# Simple code generation in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, code-generation

Is there a simple way in IntelliJ to do code generation such that the generation and resulting code is automatically integrated in the build?

I have a number of interfaces and classes that just differ by the number of parameters or things like that. I'd like to create a template and/or script or something that generates them.

Comment: You probably need to use something external to the IDE, like Ant or Maven, IntelliJ IDEA can run Ant before compilation automatically.

Comment: Have a look at the answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881406/java-crud-class-generator-for-intellij-idea/17881586#17881586) on how to setup your own code templates in intellij idea